# Harmonic maps into $SU(n)$

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request

In a famous paper [1], Schoen&Uhlenbeck claim that the theory of minimizing harmonic maps from a three-dimensional manifolds into $SU(n)$ would have been developed in a forthcoming paper, "*which may be thought of as the second part of this paper*" ([1], p. 90). This statement suggests that such a paper should have been already written (or at least the results accomplished) at the time of publishing [1]. However, I have not found any reference.

Does anyone known if it have been eventually published in some form? Was it rejected?

---

[1] R. Schoen and K. Uhlenbeck, Regularity of minimizing harmonic maps into the sphere, Inventiones Mathematicae, 1984

Comment: From [this webpage](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/uhlen/vita/vita.html), it seems that such paper does not exist.